# Search configuration page is missing the option Recently posted under content Ranking

Tags: search, drupal

I'm working on a site with Drupal 7.43. On search settings page, under the Content ranking section the option Recently posted is missing.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have found the cause of missing option. It is in node module under function node_ranking() {} at line 1780. This option is added only if variable node_cron_last has some value.

Looks like the actual problem is with the site cron or indexing of content.

Comment: Can you give us more explanation , from core search or module contrib ? It's occure after update or it was always like it ? We can't help without more details..

Comment: @Fky I'm using core search module. I was not in the team who performed upgrade so not sure if it was there on Drupal 6 or not? But a fresh Drupal 7 install on my localhost shows the option.